# Resetting In-Memory database between integration tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing

I've set up a project based on https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture. But I'm having some troubles with writing my integration tests for the controllers, since the in-memory database does not reset between each test.Each test use a WebApplicationFactory in order to set up a test web server,

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    // Remove the app's ApplicationDbContext registration.
                    var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                        d => d.ServiceType ==
                            typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));

                    if (descriptor != null)
                    {
                        services.Remove(descriptor);
                    }

                    // Add a database context using an in-memory 
                    // database for testing.
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                    });

                    // Register test services
                    services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, TestCurrentUserService>();
                    services.AddScoped<IDateTime, TestDateTimeService>();
                    services.AddScoped<IIdentityService, TestIdentityService>();

                    // Build the service provider
                    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                    // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                    // context (ApplicationDbContext).
                    using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                        var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                        // Ensure the database is created.
                        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                        try
                        {
                            // Seed the database with test data.
                            SeedSampleData(context);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the database with test messages. Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .UseEnvironment("Test");
        }
    ...
```

Where the following create test:

```
namespace CleanArchitecture.WebUI.IntegrationTests.Controllers.TodoItems
{
    public class Create : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public Create(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GivenValidCreateTodoItemCommand_ReturnsSuccessCode()
        {
            var client = await _factory.GetAuthenticatedClientAsync();

            var command = new CreateTodoItemCommand
            {
                Title = "Do yet another thing."
            };

            var content = IntegrationTestHelper.GetRequestContent(command);

            var response = await client.PostAsync($"/api/todoitems", content);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    ...
```

And the following read test:

```
namespace CleanArchitecture.WebUI.IntegrationTests.Controllers.TodoItems
{
    public class Read: IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public Read(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldRetriveAllTodos()
        {
            var client = await _factory.GetAuthenticatedClientAsync();

            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/api/todoitems");

            var todos = Deserialize(response);
            todos.Count().Should().Be(1); //but is 2 because database is shared between read and create test class.
        }
```

The problem is that the in-memory database is not reset between each test. I've tried generating a different name for the in-memory database using `Guid.New.ToString`, but then the tests don't find the seeded database data, and by putting the tests in the same XUnit collection, to no avail.

Any good ideas how to make the tests not share database?

Comment: You found any solution? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was to generate a DBName for each `WebApplicationFactory` instance, and I instantiate one of them for each test. So the test looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
  // Arrange
  var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory();
  // ...

  // Act
  // ...

  // Assert
  // ...
}
```

And the `WebApplicationFactory`:

```
    public class TestWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        private readonly string _dbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
                {
                    // This is what makes a unique in-memory database per instance of TestWebApplicationFactory
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase(_dbName);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm really curious here, your approach declaring the database name as a field works just fine. Yet when I try to call `UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())` without pre-declaring the database name as a field or variable, my tests fail, why does that happen?

Comment: Wouldn't this create a boatload of in-memory databases (ie. one for each test)? What happens once you've got a few hundred/thousand test cases?

Answer (score 3):

```
// add first 

context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Comment: ? What, where, when, & why ?

Comment: This was the fix in my case. By deleting the database first, you ensure that there are no leftover data, schema, or constraints from a previous version. This is particularly useful when you're making drastic changes to the database schema and you want to avoid any possible conflicts or errors that might arise from an existing schema.

Answer (score 2):

We isolate the test from each other in the following way when we create the DbContext:

```
private static DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> CreateDbContextOptions()
{
    return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //Database with same name gets reused, so let's isolate the tests from each other...
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) 
        .Options;
}
```

In the test class:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(DbContextTestHelper.CreateDbContextOptions())
{
    //arrange data in context

    var testee = new XY(context);

    //do test

    //do asserts
}
```

Comment: How does this isolate the tests? Extracting the DbContext registration code in another method doesn't isolate anything. What this code does is generate a *random* database name for each DbContext instance instead. This may be too much isolation. Each action may end up with a different data set

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it generates a random database name for each test

Comment: But how do I provide this newly generated DbContext to the WebApplicationFactory?

Comment: @keuleJ it generates a new database for each *context*. DbContexts are scoped, which means each action gets a new one. Calling two actions in the same test can pull data from different databases

Comment: @TheFisherman we don't use dependency injection in our test. I think you somehow have to register this instance to the scope. That way you could even use the same database for more than one scope.

Comment: and of course you have to seed the data in the same instance that you use in the test.